# Spring Batch Tasklet: SpringIntegration -vs- Curl

Tags: spring-integration, spring-batch

I'm implementing a simple ETL task with Spring Batch.

I can retrieve the input file with a simple curl command:

```
curl https://ebc.cybersource.com/ebc/DownloadReport/2016/01/14/gateway/PaymentEventsReport.csv -X GET -u user:password > eventReport.csv
```

Alternatively, I can configure a SpringIntegration tasklet to retrieve the file(s) using HTTPS.

What are the advantages to using SpringIntegration instead of using the simple 'curl' command?

Comment: Sorry: you try to compare cars and horses. You should read more docs.

Comment: The point of the question is: is Spring Integration 'overkill' in this situation?  Thanks!

Comment: I don't think so. If you have a Java application with Spring on board, what is the reason to adapt an external tools, if you simply can use out-of-the-box components?

Comment: I have programmers who don't know Spring Integration (yet) but could easily setup a 'curl' tasklet to retrieve the file.

Comment: Well, that's fine too. You should do anything you can. Afterwards you will be able convert it to to the proper Spring Integration adapter, when you'll have more knowledge for that.

Comment: if curl is enough, why do you look into spring?

Comment: Spring Batch records every tasklet in it's database and has recoverability.